# JVM Information plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jvm

Is there any plugin for Eclipse to see present JVM memory usage?
I am not looking for profilers.

`I am just looking for small plugin which can show present JVM used memory/available memory and force the Garbage Collector.`

Comment: Do you mean memory that Eclipse is using or a program that Eclipse is running?

Comment: Memory Eclipse is using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `Preferences > General` and select the `Show heap status` check box. A small display of Eclipse heap usage will appear at the bottom right of the Eclipse window.